# How to execute a condition if the value of the variable is not equal to nan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I move line by line through it to jump the image. I have empty values ​​marked as np.nan

DataFrame example:

[image]

I need to fulfill a condition under which, if the value of the passed variable is not equal to np.nan, then the image jump will be performed.

```
def save_all_images(df):
    print('Row count is dataframe:', df.shape[0])
    print('W_type image: ', df.w_type.count())
    print('Z_type image: ', df.z_type.count())
    print('Y_type image: ', df.y_type.count())
    print('R_type image: ', df.r_type.count())
    print('Q_type image: ', df.q_type.count())
    print('X_type image: ', df.x_type.count())
    
    print('\nStart save images on server')

    number = 0
    y_number = df.y_type.count()
    for i in df.iterrows():
        number = number + 1
        date = i[1][2]
        id_image = i[1][0]
        type_w = i[1][5]
        type_x = i[1][10]
        type_y = i[1][7]
        type_q = i[1][9]

        if type_w != np.nan:
            print(type(type_w))
            time.sleep(1)
            img_type_w = Image.open(requests.get(type_w, stream=True).raw)
            img_type_w.save(directory + 'w_' + str(id_image) + '_' + str(date) + '.jpg')
            img_type_w.close()
```

I know it doesn't look very good. I am getting the following error:

```
MissingSchema                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9108/1715813655.py in <module>
----> 1 save_all_images(df)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9108/3837361018.py in save_all_images(df)
     24             print(type(type_w))
     25             time.sleep(1)
---> 26             img_type_w = Image.open(requests.get(type_w, stream=True).raw)
     27             img_type_w.save(directory + 'w_' + str(id_image) + '_' + str(date) + '.jpg')
     28             img_type_w.close()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73     """
     74 
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    513             hooks=hooks,
    514         )
--> 515         prep = self.prepare_request(req)
    516 
    517         proxies = proxies or {}

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in prepare_request(self, request)
    441 
    442         p = PreparedRequest()
--> 443         p.prepare(
    444             method=request.method.upper(),
    445             url=request.url,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py in prepare(self, method, url, headers, files, data, params, auth, cookies, hooks, json)
    316 
    317         self.prepare_method(method)
--> 318         self.prepare_url(url, params)
    319         self.prepare_headers(headers)
    320         self.prepare_cookies(cookies)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py in prepare_url(self, url, params)
    390             error = error.format(to_native_string(url, 'utf8'))
    391 
--> 392             raise MissingSchema(error)
    393 
    394         if not host:

MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'nan': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://nan?
```

Comment: I would propose to use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) in combination with [df.notna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html#pandas.DataFrame.notna). Since you did not deliver reproducible code, I unfortunately can not provide a more exact answer, but you should be able to find a solution with these functions and a bit of experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should knok `np.nan == np.nan return False` so use instead [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
if not np.isnan(type_w):
    print(type(type_w))
    ....
```

Or if it is string type:

```
if type_w != 'nan':
#if type_w.replace(' ', '').lower() != 'nan': # if blanks or upper case
    print(type(type_w))
    ....
```

Comment: add error: ``` ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''```

Comment: @kostyaivanov you should check with `type_w != 'nan'`